# Angular documentation on how global controllers are handled

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for documentation or an explanation on how Angular bootstraps an application when any controllers are global.  I have no intention of adhering to this style especially long, I'm just have an audience I'm trying to explain Angular to, and don't want to cover modules at the very beginning.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap is pretty clear for when a module is used instead of globally declared controllers:

"Angular looks for the ng-app directive which designates your application root. If the ng-app directive is found then Angular will:

- load the module associated with the directive.
- create the application injector
- compile the DOM treating the ng-app directive as the root of the compilation"

Just looking for something reasonably comparable and understandable for when a controller is declared globally, instead of using a module, thanks.

Comment: if `ng-app` is not assigned  a value in markup...don't even need a module declared just to run controllers.... hard to add directives though without module. To be honest it should be fairly easy to introduce `module` syntax as starting point without needing to get deep into what it is. Will help with being able to frame the basic components like directives, controllers and services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/controller.js)

Angular does these things to get a-hold of the controller constructor (which it then keeps):

- check if a controller with given name is registered via `$controllerProvider`
- check if evaluating the string on the current scope returns a constructor
- check `window[constructor]` on the global `window` object